# Issue with complex Django join query

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I can't find a valid way with Django OMR in order to get : ( a raw query is also fine )

the Sites.sitename which made the Analysis where (Analysi_Items.name='somename' and Analysis_Items.value='somevalue') and (Analysi_items_name='somename' and Analysis_Items.value='somevalue') and (Analysis_items.name='somename' and Analysis_Items.value='somevalue').

```
class Sites(models.Model):

    region = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    sitename = models.CharField(max_length=1000, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:

        verbose_name_plural = "Sites"

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.sitename

class Analysis_Items(models.Model):

        code = models.ForeignKey('Analysis')
        name = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
        value = models.CharField(max_length=20)

        class Meta:

            verbose_name_plural = "Analysis Type"

class Analysis(models.Model):

        date = models.DateField()
        site = models.ForeignKey('Sites')

        def __unicode__(self):

            return str(self.date)

        class Meta:

            verbose_name_plural = "Analysis"
```

Hope this is clear enough. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Site.objects.filter(analysis__analysis_items__name='some_name', analysis__analysis_items__value='some_value')
```

You can keep adding additional parameters in the same keep AND'ing them all together.